# How is it that I can attach strace to a process that isn't in the output of ps?

Tags: process, ps, strace

I'm trying to debug why our integration tests are taking so long and it looks like they're hanging part way through.

I logged onto our test service and saw the following behaviour:

```
root@colossus:~# strace -p 18310
Process 18310 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x7f9915c609d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 18313, NULL^C <unfinished ...>
Process 18310 detached

root@colossus:~# strace -p 18313
Process 18313 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>^C <unfinished ...>
Process 18313 detached

root@colossus:~# ps -ef | grep 18313
root     19089 19034  0 09:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 18313

root@colossus:~# ps -p 18313
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

My interpretation of these commands is that `18310` is waiting for its child `18313` to complete.

Process `18313` is trying to restart an interrupted system call.

Here's where it gets weird. Although I can attach to `18313`, I cannot see it in the list of current processes, when I run `ps`.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here, please?

Comment: That's a thread. Use `ps -L`. See also `strace -f` to strace all the threads in that process (and future children)

Comment: Please add that as an answer, so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

Per Stéphane's comment, what I'm seeing is a thread, not a process.

Threads are listed in the output from `ps -L`

One can strace all current and future threads of a process with `strace -f`