# What information can I find out about an eventpoll on a running thread?

Tags: process, thread

*Following on from a problem described in "[How is it that I can attach strace to a process that isn't in the output of ps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126133/how-is-it-that-i-can-attach-strace-to-a-process-that-isnt-in-the-output-of-ps)"*

I'm trying to debug a process that hangs part way through.

By using `strace -f` on my parent process, I was able to determine that I have a bunch of threads that are just showing:

```
# strace -p 26334
Process 26334 attached - interrupt to quit
epoll_wait(607, {}, 4096, 500)          = 0
epoll_wait(607, {}, 4096, 500)          = 0
epoll_wait(607, {}, 4096, 500)          = 0
epoll_wait(607, {}, 4096, 500)          = 0
epoll_wait(607, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 26334 detached
```

Investigating further:

```
# readlink /proc/26334/fd/607
anon_inode:[eventpoll]
```

My gut tells me that I've managed to get some threads in a deadlock situation, but I don't really know enough about `epoll` to move forward. Are there any commands that can give me some insight into what these threads are polling for, or which file descriptors this epoll descriptor maps to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `strace` the lines it's returning are system functions. In case it wasn't obvious `epoll_wait()` is a function that you can do a [`man epoll_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) to find out implementation details like so:

```
   epoll_wait, epoll_pwait - wait for an I/O event on an epoll file descriptor
```

The description for `epoll`:

> The  epoll  API  performs  a  similar  task to poll(2): monitoring multiple file descriptors to see if I/O is possible on any of them.  The epoll API can be used either as an edge-triggered or a level-triggered interface and scales well to large numbers of watched file descriptors.

So it would seem that you're process is blocking on file descriptors, waiting to see if I/O is possible on any of them.

I would change my tactics a bit and try and make use of `lsof -p <pid>` to see if you can narrow down what these files actually are.

Comment: any hint how to troubleshoot further? What is being waited on?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk - is this directed to me? I haven't heard anything further since the OP posted this almost 1 year ago 8-).

Comment: this question is directed to anybody who can answer it. I hope our savior will find the way here due to the excellent site, question and answer.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk I'd post it as a follow-up Q, if you want something more specific, no one will see this comment here except you and me. Be sure to reference this question and state what further details you're after.

Comment: lsof -p didn't help me much, I basically see a line like this:
node    2281 tony   13u  a_inode   0,14        0    11498 [eventpoll:14,16]