# What is anon_inode in the output of "ls -l /proc/[PID]/fd"?

Tags: linux, proc, file-types

While looking through `/proc/[PID]/fd/` folder of various processes, I found  curious entry for `dbus`

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 05:46 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
```

Hence the question, what are `anon_inode`s ? Are these similar to anonymous pipes ?

Comment: Some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508998/what-is-an-anonymous-inode-in-linux).

Comment: Some related anonymous inode concepts that might be of interest can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508998/what-is-an-anonymous-inode-in-linux/44388030#44388030 e.g. `O_TMPFILE` and epoll.

Comment: Thanks, will check

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything under `/proc` is covered in the [`man proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). This section covers `anon_inode`.

> For  file  descriptors  for  pipes  and  sockets, the entries will be symbolic links whose content is the file type with the inode.  A readlink(2) call on this file
>     returns a string in the format:
>
> ```
>  type:[inode]
> ```
>
> For example, `socket:[2248868]` will be a socket and its inode is 2248868.  For sockets, that inode can be used to find more information in one  of  the  files  under
>     `/proc/net/`.
>
> For  file  descriptors  that  have  no  corresponding  inode  (e.g.,  file  descriptors  produced  by `epoll_create(2)`, `eventfd(2)`, `inotify_init(2)`, `signalfd(2)`, and
>     `timerfd(2))`, the entry will be a symbolic link with contents of the form
>
> ```
>  anon_inode:<file-type>
> ```
>
> In some cases, the file-type is surrounded by square brackets.
>
> For example, an epoll file descriptor will have a symbolic link whose content is the string `anon_inode:[eventpoll]`.

For more on `epoll` I discuss them here - [What information can I find out about an eventpoll on a running thread?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126196/what-information-can-i-find-out-about-an-eventpoll-on-a-running-thread).

For additional information on `anon_inode`'s - [What is an anonymous inode in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508998/what-is-an-anonymous-inode-in-linux). Basically there is/was data on disk that no longer has a filesystem reference to access it. An `anon_inode` shows that there's a file descriptor which has no referencing inode.

Comment: OK, so "...file descriptors that have no corresponding inode..." So if inode is a data structure related to filesystems, does that mean that `anon_inode` is basically a file that doesn't live on disk and is mapped in memory somewhere ? In my example it's `eventpoll` type, but I don't even know what that is and didn't even know `eventpoll` exists till today, so at the very basic level, what is `anon_inode` after all ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - at basic level `anon_inode` could've been something that was a file but is no longer on the disk. `epoll` is for monitoring multiple file descriptors, similar to `poll` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll

Comment: OK that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - the src for `anon_inodes` might be helpful too - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/anon_inodes.c.

Answer (score 1):

These come from the [epoll](https://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll) syscalls for monitoring multiple other file descriptors. Nothing to do with anonymous pipes.